# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to project.model.Role

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to display a role name and it's id from a table using a join value.

What should happen is this :

- User logs in, id of the user is kept in a variable
- We query the join table "user_roles" to get list of roles that a user have, the join table have two Keys : "iduser" and "idrole" which are both foreign keys to User table and Role table
- Then I need to display the role by it's name (on list of roles) and this gives me :

  java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to prj.model.Role
  javax.faces.FacesException: #{userloginMB.login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to prj.model.Role

My Role file is as follows :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="ROLES") 
public class Role {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idrole;


        public int getIdrole() {
        return idrole;
    }

    public void setIdrole(int idrole) {
        this.idrole = idrole;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    private String role; 
}
```

My Query is like this :

```
    public List<Role[]> getRolesByUserId(int iduser) {
//Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Role r INNER JOIN r.userRoles a where a.iduser  = :Iduser").setParameter("Iduser", iduser);
List<Role[]> list = (List<Role[]>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM roles WHERE idrole IN (SELECT idrole FROM User_Roles WHERE iduser = :Iduser)").setParameter("Iduser", iduser).list();

return list;
}
```

Managed bean functions getting role :

```
public List<Role[]> getUserRoles() {
    if(userRoles == null){
        userRoles = new ArrayList<Role[]>();
        userRoles.addAll(getRoleService().getRoleByUserId(getIduser()));

    }
    return userRoles;
}

public void setUserRoles(List<Role[]>  userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
}
```

And the display, finally :

```
            userRoles = getUserRoles();
            for (Role[] role : userRoles){
                System.out.println(role[1].getIdrole());
                System.out.println(role[1].getRole());
            }
```

*Note: I know manually that the table have two entries to that user that's why I'm testing like this before creating a foreach or any repeater.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, additionally to what kucing_terbang said, you have to change the  to  as you are getting a List of Roles and not a List of composed objects of type Role, and try this :

```
                System.out.println(getUserRoles().get(0).getIdrole());
                System.out.println(getUserRoles().get(0).getRole());
```

(Then you can show all data using a for boucle or a foreach ...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you're using a native SQL query which will return a "raw" values.

To make the hibernate gives you the `Role` class, you can set the entity type like this.

```
createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM roles WHERE idrole IN (SELECT idrole FROM User_Roles WHERE iduser = :Iduser)").setParameter("Iduser", iduser).addEntity(Role.class).list();
```

for further reference, check the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: I still get this : project.model.Role cannot be cast to [Lproject.model.Role;